# Импорт модуля из родительского каталога

Tags: python, модули, импорт

Необходимо импортировать функцию из модуля(f1), лежащего папкой выше(в folder1) в модуль f2 лежащий в folder2.
Вариант с sys.path.append("путь к папке") помогает, но к сожалению не устраивает изначально.
Пробовал добавлять `__init__` по папкам и обращаться from folder.f1 и т.д - ничего не помогло (ModuleNotFoundError).
Что делаю не так? Возможно в `__init__` надо что-то прописать?

[[image: см скриншот]]

Answer (score 1):

Делайте относительный импорт:

```
# фрагмент из f2.py
from ..f1 import f
```

В общем случае можно указывать и родителя родителя и т.д:

```
from ..module_in_parent_package import some_func
from .. import other_func    # импорт из __init__ родителя или импорт модуля из родителя
from ...module_in_grandparent_package import yet_other_func
```

Comment: При таком относительном импорте происходит ошибка:ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package